# findAndUpdate MongoDBRepository

Tags: json, mongodb, rabbitmq, ddd-repositories, spring-data

My task is to create repository extending MongoDBRepository that allows me to define kind of findAndUpdate method. MongoOps and template approach is not allowed. This is how my MongoDocument looks like:

```
{"_id":"somedocumentId","attributetype1":{"class":"type1","value":"somevalue"}, 
             "attributetype2":{"class":"type2","value":"somevalue"},
             "attributetype3":{{"class":"type2","value":"somevalue"},{"class":"type2","value":"somevalue"},...,}
```

As you can see some atributes are just class values, while others are lists.
Here is the update request I receive from my messaging subsystem:

```
{"documentId":"somedocumentIdValue","updatedata":{"class":"typeX","value":"somevalue"}
```

If type of request data is just a class value (like attributetype1 and 2) I need to update it, if update data is of type that is save as a list I need to append it.

What would you suggest in this case?

Comment: Are you saying that you can't use mongo's findAndModify? Why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to determine whether or not to do a `$set` or a `$push` so there seems to be three choices.

1. Update the messaging subsystem to include the operator.

   *This may not be feasible..*
2. Issue a [findAndModify](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) with a `$push`.

   This will fail if its not an array:

   > Cannot apply $push/$pushAll modifier to non-array

   So reissue with a `$set`

   *Feels like a hack but will work*
3. Do a query that returns the document and inspect it and then issue the correct operator in an update query.

   *More code required in the application*